# How can I reveal these groups inside of collections in blender 2.9

Tags: collections, outliner

I have project that I worked on in blender 2.6/2.7x and now Im decided to switch to blender 2.9 but  when I open that file I'v got some groups which are gread out and dont see them i view port. How can I make them visable again ?

[image]

Comment: @JachymMichal yes it does tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click this button and you will get dropdown for restriction tools
Click on monitor looking icon.
[image]

Now you can see additional icons  for your objects and collections.
Greyed out object should have monitor icon disabled
[image]

Enable the icon to make objects/collection visible again.

Now, you may ask what's the difference between `Eye` icon and `Monitor` icon visibility.

- Visibility controlled by `eye` icon is bound to current view layer.
  which means it does not affect the visibility of object in other view
  layer.
- Visibility controlled by `Monitor` icon is global which means if you
  disable it in current view layer then object's visibility in all other view layers are disabled.